# How to pass complex object to swagger param function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, object, swagger, param

When I create auto documented API specification, I faced with problem of passing **complex object** (ActiveRecord for ex.) to **param** function of [swagger-docs](https://github.com/richhollis/swagger-docs)/[swagger-ui_rails](https://github.com/d4be4st/swagger-ui_rails), because it takes only simple types (string, integer, ...).

I solved this trouble with next metaprogramming ruby trick:

```
class Swagger::Docs::SwaggerDSL
  def param_object(klass, params={})
    klass_ancestors = eval(klass).ancestors.map(&:to_s)
    if klass_ancestors.include?('ActiveRecord::Base')
      param_active_record(klass, params)
    end
  end

  def param_active_record(klass, params={})
    remove_attributes = [:id, :created_at, :updated_at]
    remove_attributes += params[:remove] if params[:remove]

    test = eval(klass).new
    test.valid?
    eval(klass).columns.each do |column|
      unless remove_attributes.include?(column.name.to_sym)
        param column.name.to_sym,
              column.name.to_sym,
              column.type.to_sym,
              (test.errors.messages[column.name.to_sym] ? :required : :optional),
              column.name.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now I can use **param_object** for complex objects as **param** for simple types :

```
swagger_api :create do
  param :id, :id, :integer, :required, "Id"
  param_object('Category')
end
```

[image]

**Git fork here:**

https://github.com/abratashov/swagger-docs